# Can an SVG be imported as an <svg> tag WITHOUT copy-pasting the SVG code?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a folder of several SVGs, all of which I'm trying to include in my HTML file.

I'm using the paper.js library to analyze the SVGs, and to my knowledge **the only way it works is by using the `<svg>` tag** — so importing the svgs using `<object>` or `<img>` won't work.

I'm trying to find a systematic way to do this, so that I won't have to copy-paste all of the SVG code from each individual file (100+).

Do you know if this is possible?
Do you have any suggestions for potential alternatives?

Comment: read them using ajax solution of your choice (XHR, fetch, jQuery,  etc) this is assuming you are hosting these on some sort of (local?) http server of course

Comment: Could you show how you normally do *analyse the SVGs* with paper.js? I'm almost certain you can do this on framed svg nodes too.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the suggestion, I haven't tried it out but I'm fairly certain something like that would work. Thanks for your thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Assuming Windows, couldn't you just copy all of the contents into a single file?  E.g.:

```
copy *.svg index.html
```

And then edit index.html so it has `<html>` and `<body>` tags, etc.

SVG files are just text, so I think all you need to do is concatenate all of the files.

It's pretty easy in MacOS/Linux too.  I think you could just `cat` them all into a file like this:

```
cat *.svg > index.html
```

But perhaps there's a cleaner way.

Comment: If any of the SVG files have id values that are the same this won't work. All ids will need to be unique in the combined file.

Comment: Yep, valid point @RobertLongson.  The HTML would be invalid in that case... although I'm not sure whether it would affect the rendering since most browsers handle that transparently to the user viewing the page.  Nonetheless, effects of duplicate IDs can cause wacky and hard to debug behavior, and you are 100% correct.  My solution assumes unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Never played with the `paper.js` library, so can't confirm if this technique exhibits any wrinkles. Basically, I'd take the same approach mentioned by  Jaromanda X, and have the page pull all the images it needs via AJAX. You'll need to add error-checking and ensure the code is robust - I've not even attempted this, merely providing code that will function when all is as expected. I'm serving from `localhost` and the images are in the same folder as the html file. (Serving from the local file-system fails due to cross-origin requests when retrieving the SVGs)

---

**Update:** As kindly pointed out by Robert Longson in a comment below, one manner in which this code has not been hardened and will almost certainly fail, is in the insertion of multiple images with the same `id`. If images aren't located by their `id` they code may produce a usable output. However, it *will always* produce invalid markup whenever the same id appears more than once.

A potential work-around would be to load all of the images into an off-screen collection before processing any of them. You could then check for clashing `id`s and alter those that repeat already valid ones.

---

### loadSVGS.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

var filenames = ['blueBomb.svg','cpBob.svg'];

function ajaxGet(url, onLoad, onError)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onload = function(){onLoad(this);}
    ajax.onerror = function(){console.log("ajax request failed to: "+url);onError(this);}
    ajax.open("GET",url,true);
    ajax.send();
}

function mInit()
{
    filenames.forEach( loadImage );
}

function loadImage(filename)
{
    ajaxGet(filename, onLoaded, onFailed);
}

function onLoaded(ajax)
{
    var div = newEl('div');
    div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function onFailed(ajax)
{
    console.log('bugger!');
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If any of the SVG files have id values that are the same this won't work. All ids will need to be unique once they have all been loaded into the main document.

Comment: Didn't even consider that potential problem. Had hoped (perhaps naively) that some code with a disclaimer was better than nothing. Reckon I should remove the answer?

Comment: Maybe just add a warning to make sure this isn't the case. Any conflicts could be fixed up manually beforehand or the code could be enhanced to assign unique ids on load, making sure to fix up any references of course.